# Invoking ${_csrf.parameterName} & ${_csrf.token} in the logout form through url click instead

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hello I'm learning security through Spring, I read a sentence from tutorial that *If CSRF is enabled, you have to include a `_csrf.token` 
in the page you want to login or logout.*

Here's how I invoke them through submit button :

```
    <c:url var="logoutAction" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />                
        <form action="${logoutAction}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

My question is how if they're got invoked in the form of *`<a href="..">`* :

```
<c:url var="logoutAction" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />    
<a href="${logoutAction}"> logout</a>
```

How I invoke *csrf* protection in the above form, I hope you get my question Thank you.

Comment: Is this about style? Do you want that button looks like link? You can do that with css.

Comment: Hello thank, I mean , does it make sense to invoke csrf protection under link based logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured it incorrectly, you should first include the spring tag library using JSP directive like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

then within your form just make sure that you this included:

```
<sec:csrfInput />
```

for example:

```
<form method="post" action="/do/something">
        <sec:csrfInput />
        Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        ...
</form>
```

Do the same for logout link, use a form. here's an example from my project:

```
<form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action='<c:url value="/logout"/>'>
    <sec:csrfInput/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include csrf inside your logout path, i.e. `/yourapp/logout?[csrf_param_name]=[csrf_token]`.